# Merge images in PHP - GIF and JPG

Tags: php, gd, gif, jpeg

I am trying to merge *two images* - a **GIF** image with a smaller **JPG** image. The output should be **GIF**.

**The issue** is that **GIF** image colors remain correct, but the colors of the **JPG** image are altered.

The **GIF** image has only 256 colors (8-bit), but is there a way to make the merged image to be a true-color resource which later can be converted to a 8-bit **GIF** for output?

---

*Issue solved.*

---

**I updated the code. Here is the solution which works fine:**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: image/gif');

$gif_address = 'file.gif';
$jpg_address = 'file.jpg';

$image1 = imagecreatefromgif($gif_address);
$image2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($jpg_address);

$merged_image = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 800);
imagecopymerge($merged_image, $image1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 800, 800, 100);
imagecopymerge($merged_image, $image2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, 500, 100);

imagegif($merged_image);

imagedestroy($image1);
imagedestroy($image2);
imagedestroy($merged_image);

?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your explanation (some code would help), i would hazard a guess you are merging the jpeg onto the gif.  Id say the easiest way is to use **imageCreateTrueColor** to create a new image the size you need then use **imagecopy** to copy the GIF into this new image.  Merge the jpg onto this and then at a later date you can covert the true colour image to a gif.

If im missing something a bit of example code of what you are currently doing might help.

Comment: Yes **imageCreateTrueColor** works perfectly. Perhaps, using **imagecopy** instead of **imagecopymerge** is a good idea. Thank You!